# Excel formula issue

Tags: sql, excel, excel-formula

Can someone explain to me what is wrong with my formula? To me, it looks like it should work. I have no clue as to what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please explain to me what it's doing? Thank you!

The error is in the false condition of the IF function although I'm not sure why.

The logic:
 
Column A consists of strings.
 If Column A1 = "Loyalty" then 82, else put in the subquery (which requires for A1 to be pulled).

```
="INSERT INTO QuestCluster VALUES(4657, "&B1&","IF(A1 = "Loyalty", 82, "(select questclassificationID from QuestClassifications where Classification = '"&A1&"')")",1)"
```

I'm getting the old "There's a problem with this formula" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing some ampersands. Try this one.

```
="INSERT INTO QuestCluster VALUES(4657, "&B1&","&IF(A1 = "Loyalty", 82,"(select questclassificationID from QuestClassifications where Classification = '"&A1&"')")&",1)"
```